# Should I be replacing my laptop's LCD, or its internal LCD cable based on these photos?

Tags: laptop, display, lcd

I received an Aspire One 10.1 inch laptop after a friend dropped it and it became unusable.

The screen looks like this:

[image: Screen 1].

Basically four sections, the left and right sections are repeated, and the middle two sections are as you see them (although they sometimes change the pattern of lines or colours)

Furthermore, the laptop will occasionally boot up, and the entire right half will be covered in those scanlines (that is, there wont be a repeated desktop on the right side, the corruption will extend all the way to the right)

An external monitor works fine.

My question is, is there any way I can verify whether it's the actual LCD panel or just the LCD data cable that's faulty? I'd hate to pay $20 for a cable online and then find out I actually need the $70 LCD panel or something.

Furthermore, I've always had trouble finding consistent prices for these sorts of parts online; does anybody have a source for reliable and fair-priced laptop LCD screens or parts?

THanks again, you guys have always been helpful,
--Dave

Comment: what happens when you plug the VGA cable into an external monitor? Unlikely, but good to make sure that the motherboard/video card isn't messed up

Comment: Which VGA cable? Plugging a regular external monitor into the VGA port on the side of the netbook works just fine; the picture is uncorrupted. As for the LCD cable within the laptop, it's a flat custom cable that also carries the webcam data and connects to the motherboard; I'm not sure how I'd test that cable, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up replacing the LCD panel.